# From plane parametric to normal equations and viceversa.

Tags: geometry, vectors

When I have a plane, I can calculate two equations:

**Parametric**, of the form
$$P + s\cdot \vec{q} + t \cdot \vec{r}$$
For some point $P$ in the plane, two direction arrows $\vec{q},\vec{r}$ that are not parallel, and some $s,r\in \mathbb{R}$.

**Normal**, of the form

$$ax+by+cz = d$$
With only one point and one direction arrow perpendicular to the plane.

---

I am wondering, is it possible, given one form, to transform it into the other?

Here I have two planes:

$$A: x - y + 2z = 10\\
B: (1,1,1)+t(1,-1,1)+s(0,1,0)$$

$A$ is normal and $B$ is parametric. How can I transform $A$ to parametric and $B$ to normal?

I happen to know that a normal form of $B$ is

$$-x+z=0$$

From a previous exercise, but I'm not sure what was done to achieve this form.

Comment: Let $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)+t(1,-1,1)+s(0,1,0)$. Then, solve these simultaneous equations. Then, you will get $-x+z=0$ and whatever $y$ suffices the equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
A=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:x-y+2z=10\}
$$
Note that the vector $(1,-1,2)$ is normal to $A$ and that $(10,0,0)\in A$. Since
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Null}{Null}\Null\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&2\end{bmatrix}=
\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{
\begin{bmatrix}-2&0&1 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\end{bmatrix}
\}
$$
we may write
$$
A=\{(10,0,0)+r\cdot(-2,0,1)+s\cdot(1,1,0)\in\Bbb R^3:r,s\in\Bbb R\}
$$

Now, let 
$$
B=\{(1,1,1)+r(1,-1,1)+s(0,1,0)\in\Bbb R^3:r,s\in\Bbb R\}
$$
Note that
$$
(1,-1,1)\times(0,1,0)=(-1,0,1)
$$
Can you use this equation to finish putting $B$ into normal form?

Comment: I'm kind of unfamiliar with that Null[] = Span{} thing you did there, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

We have $x - y + 2 z = 10$ then $x = 10 + y - 2 z$. We deduce that the parametric form of the plane is :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
x & = & 10 + r - 2 s \\[2mm]
x & = & r \\[2mm]
x & = & s 
\end{array}\right.$$